# How to get correct page on site that doesn't change URL

Tags: java, http-post

I need to go around a site using java programmatically but the site doesn't change the url when linked is clicked.

Site: http://cliqa.nana10.co.il/

On the right you have a bar with some links, click them and you will see that while the content changes the url doesn't change. how can i achieve programmatically this mouse click on one of the links in Java, I thought about HTTP POST but what exactly I'm going to send? an example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the actual HTTP request being sent. You can do this Chrome with the built in Inspect Element tool or Firebug in Firefox (or Live HTTP Headers). I prefer to use [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html)'s intercepting proxy to see this.

Comment: can it be this? i found it in the inspect element under Rquest Payload:  {'pageId':'0', 'pageCategory':'6', 'pageArea':'all', 'horizontal':'false' , 'orderBy':'0'}

Comment: That appears to be some JSON that is being sent. You will need to look at the request headers and the data that is being sent. Is that the only thing that is being sent across?

Answer (score 1):

These links use JavaScript to trigger an AJAX request and refresh only the center of the page. Use FireBug inside Firefox to sniff the network requests and see which requests are executed on each click. Or use a programmatic web browser like [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net) which will handle JavaScript as your web browser does.

Answer (score 0):

You can try charles (http://www.charlesproxy.com/). Check the section on JAVA APPLICATION PROXY CONFIGURATION at http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/configuration/browser-and-system-configuration/. You can inspect and change request sent from your java application.